# unix TOP command doesn't work with PID

Tags: android, unix

So I'm writing for android. My application needs the data regarding apps' Memory and CPU usage.
Pretty quickly I found out that no Android function can help me and so I can use the "TOP" command.
My problem is that I need to provide certain PIDs but the command doesn't work.
When I read the lines I get null.
I checked the syntax and all seems legit.
Any ideas?

Code:

```
            for(int j=0; j<20;j++)
            {
                pids+=PIDs[j].toString()+",";
            }
            pids=pids.substring(0,pids.length()-1);
            String command = "top -m 20 -p "+ pids +" -n 1";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            int i = 7;
            do {
                line = reader.readLine();
                i--;
            }while(i>0);

            while (line != null)
            {
                list.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            p.waitFor();
```

Comment: which command doesn't work? `top`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the latest source code from the [AOSP](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1//xref/system/core/toolbox/top.c#408), sadly the -p command is not supported. If you directly call your command in the android shell, you should get an invalid argument "-p" error.